# Please delete my question

Tags: discussion

[How can I convince an employer not to go out of business?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49236/how-can-i-convince-an-employer-not-to-go-out-of-business/49237#49237)

You won't let me edit it, you won't let me comment on the existing answer to correct someone who is leading people to believe the employer will only be able to pay their bills on a good year when I meant I will only be able to pay my bills on a good year, and you won't let me use meta.

This has been wholly unproductive. You've completely removed my ability to use the site do get other peoples suggestions on the issue. Absolutely nothing I can do to use the site at all, just silenced to completeness.

Comment: I'm sure unintentionally but the points system sure screwed me over on this.

Comment: If you registered as a user you could edit your own question.

Comment: You are showing up as two different users.  Fix that and you should be able to edit your post.  Also, even with this account, a suggested edit might have been accepted.

Comment: The question is a reasonable question.  I don't know why it was closed, which was why I answered it.  I feel that with some minor edits it could be reopened.

Comment: I don't get it, you can always edit your own posts, regardless of reputation. What is the error you are facing when you try to edit?

Comment: This question has been reopened.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry you're having some frustrations with the site.  Nobody intended to silence you.

It appears that you have two different accounts, which is causing you problems.  The first one is unregistered, which means you only have access to it via a cookie set in the browser you used to create it.  Registered accounts don't have that limitation.  It looks like you've registered this one, which is good.

You can always edit your own posts (meaning from the same account), and while it requires 50 reputation to comment anywhere, you can always comment on your own posts.  If you keep using this new account you shouldn't run into the problems you had on that question.

If you've lost access to the other account and want to regain control of the question, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the site to ask that the accounts be merged.  The question was put on hold as too broad, not off-topic, so if you edit it it can probably be reopened.  Putting questions on hold is not meant to be permanent.

You can still propose an edit to the question; since the system doesn't recognize it as yours (because of the two accounts) that edit will need to be approved by reviewers, but if you make an effort to improve the question (addressing the feedback you got in comments) it should get approved.  You might want to identify yourself as the OP in the edit summary, which reviewers can see.

Comment: I manually copied rejected edit into the question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/49236/revisions

Comment: @gnat, thanks for finding and fixing that.  user37816, it looks like the reviewers didn't know that you were editing your own post (because of the different accounts) and thought somebody was making an inappropriate change.  The edit has sent the question to the review queue for reopening.